# How to evaluate real and imaginary part of $\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, gamma-function, cauchy-principal-value

I calculated the principal value of the following integral:
$$PV\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{-t}}{1-3t}dt=\left(\frac{\Im\left[\left(-1\right)^{\frac{5}{6}}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right]}{\sqrt[3]{3e}}-1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\approx -0.225197$$
I know that
$$(-1)^{5/6}=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}$$
But I don't know how to express the real and the imaginary part of $\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)$
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)=\int_{-\frac{1}{3}}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{2/3-1}\mathrm{d}t\approx 1.7682-0.717204 i$$

---

*Edit*
A resolution like this would be fine too
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)=\underbrace{\int_{a_1}^{b_1}f_1(t)\mathrm{d}t}_{\in\mathbb{R}}+i \underbrace{\int_{a_2}^{b_2}f_2(t)\mathrm{d}t}_{\in\mathbb{R}}$$

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe there's a closed formula for that?

Comment: @jjagmath There are a lot of formulas that I certainly don't know, maybe someone knows one that comes in handy for me (I don't know... maybe there is a special function defined in the form of an integral that can express those values)

Comment: @jjagmath something like $\displaystyle\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)=\int_A a(x)\mathrm{d}x+i\int_B b(x)\mathrm{d}x$ that would be just as good.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If, for example, this is part of a book exercise, one would expect it to have a reasonable answer. Is that the case? Or may be this is part of a research of an open problem?

Comment: @jjagmath Ah, no, I don't know. I simply did the count and that quantity appeared which I can't calculate with real functions.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be converted to hypegeometric ...
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \!{{{\rm e}^{-t}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{t}}}}\,{\rm d}t
&=\Gamma\left(\frac23\right) \qquad\text{[real]}
\\
\int_{-1/3}^0 \!{{{\rm e}^{-t}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{t}}}}\,{\rm d}t
&=
-{\frac { \left( i{3}^{{5/6}}-\sqrt [3]{3} \right) {{\rm e}^{{
1/3}}}}{20\, }\left( 
{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(1;\,{\frac{8}{3}};\,-{\frac{1}{3}})}-5 \right) }
\\&=
{\frac { \left(\sqrt [3]{3} \right) {{\rm e}^{{
1/3}}}}{20\, }\left( 
{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(1;\,{\frac{8}{3}};\,-{\frac{1}{3}})}-5 \right) }
\qquad\text{[real]}
\\&\qquad
- i{\frac { \left( {3}^{{5/6}} \right) {{\rm e}^{{
1/3}}}}{20\, }\left( 
{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(1;\,{\frac{8}{3}};\,-{\frac{1}{3}})}-5 \right) }
\qquad\text{[purely imaginary]}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$\Gamma\left(\frac23,-\frac13\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)-\left(-\frac13\right)^\frac23S,S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{3^n\left(n+\frac23\right)n!}=\sqrt[3]{-1}3^\frac23\left(\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)-\Gamma\left(\frac23,-\frac13\right)\right)$$

we get

$$\operatorname{Re}\Gamma\left(\frac23,-\frac13\right)= \Gamma\left(\frac23\right)+\frac S{2\cdot3^\frac23}=\left(1-\frac{\sqrt[3]{-1}}2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)+\frac{\sqrt[3]{-1}}2\Gamma\left(\frac23,-\frac13\right)$$

and

$$\operatorname{Im} \Gamma\left(\frac23,-\frac13\right)=-\frac S{2\sqrt[6]3}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{-1}\sqrt3}2\gamma\left(\frac23,-\frac13\right)$$

with the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cgamma%28a%2Cz%29). Both are [shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B%7B%281-%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%2F2%29+gamma%282%2F3%29%2B%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29%2F2+gamma%282%2F3%2C-1%2F3%29%2C%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29+%E2%88%9A3%2F2+%5Cgamma%282%2F3%2C-1%2F3%29%7D%2C10%5D)

Comment: Ok, but in this solution you are using functions that give complex values, keep in mind that I use programs that only work with real numbers. If I pass it as input that solution gives me undefined. $\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)$ is an "undefined" value in real numbers

Answer (score 0):

I tried to avoid the hypergeometric function and arrived at the following result.

\begin{align}
\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right) =& \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left( \frac{2 \pi }{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}-a\right)+ a \; I \\
a = & \frac{1}{4} \left(-3\; b-3^{5/6}\; e^{1/3}+\sqrt{3} \; \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)  \\
b= & (-1)^{1/3} \sqrt{3}\; \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{3},-\frac{1}{3}\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) I   \\
\end{align}

Where $a$ is a real $(-0.7172039326..)$ equal to the imaginary part of  $\Gamma(2/3,-1/3)$

And $b$ is a real $(0.5759692781..)$ defined by the incomplete gamma function cancelling its imaginary part.